# How do I add multiple, independent views to a single storyboard scene?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode5

I'm new to the practice of Storyboards in Xcode, and I'm having a problem trying to do what I used do when I only used xib files for layouts.

Sometimes when I make a view, it will need one or more small secondary views that are independent of the layout of the main view. Usually these smaller views are things like a custom keyboard for an input field, or a toolbar with a few buttons on it that I'll attach on top of a keyboard (e.g. adding a "Done" button above a number pad keyboard, since they lack one for some reason).

When I used xib files to do this, I could just drag a new view anywhere on the canvas, and it would just "float" there, independent of the other views in the xib. I could then setup it's own layout and wire the buttons to the outlet properties of the same view controller that the main view was connected to.

Now when I use a storyboard to do my view layouts instead of xib files, I can no longer put views wherever I want on the canvas. Storyboards are more restricted/organized, and each independent view seems like it has to be in its own "scene". So when I try to do what I did in xib files, I run into a problem. It only lets me put view *controllers* on the canvas, not plain old views.

I've tried dragging a view directly into the "View Outline" left side panel so that I can get it where I want in the view hierarchy; however, when this extra view isn't inside the main view, I cannot see it anywhere on the screen. Maybe the best why to explain this is with images.

Here's what I normally do in xib files:
[image: xib file showing extra views]

In the xib file you can see the two views existing independently (one is not nested inside the other). In this example, I'll end up connecting the extra view to an outlet property in the view controller/file's owner. Then inside "viewDidLoad", I'll assign it to the ".inputView" property of the UITextField so that it replaces the keyboard with a view that has a date picker, a label, and a done button.

Here's what my (failed) attempt looks like in a Storyboard file:
[image]

So I tried to get another view into the same scene. What I find in Storyboard files is that anything that isn't nested inside the main view doesn't show up anywhere. So I can't setup anything on my extra view file because I can't see it on the screen; it's only visible in the View Outline panel. This makes what I used to do in xib files not possible anymore.

The only other way I can think of to make these extra views now is to add a separate xib file for each one alongside my Storyboard, which to me seems kind of silly, since I thought Storyboards were supposed to eliminate the need for having a xib for each view. The old way seemed so simple, so what do I do now? Maybe I'm going about this entirely the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: from my understanding, storyboards are more about the flow from controller to controller. in my current apps i'm still using xibs for custom views. one idea you could try is to just put a second view inside the controller outside the main view. the simulated controller sizes are not what they'll be displayed as anyways, so you can expand each controller in the xib as much as you want to edit it.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just double click your second view in the document outline on the left. Your view will show up on the storyboard near the scene that contains it.